# What is the difference between <EOF and <'EOF' in shell heredocs?

Tags: shell, sh

I'm writing a .spec file for a module for linux build system and came across a small issue and wanted to share it.

For writing a script file :

```
cat <<EOF > /path/to/somewhere/script
#blah blah
EOF
chmod +x script
```

When the script ran on the target there were errors pointing to the location of the script as it were in the host system.Basically $0 was wrong.

Fixed it by changing the first line like this after seeing some sample code online:

```
cat <<'EOF' > /path/to/somewhere/script
#blah blah
EOF
chmod +x script
```

Wondering what's the difference and what made it work the second time.

Comment: You mentioned an error message. What was it? Please do not paraphrase.

Comment: The `chmod` should, surely, use the same file name as the redirection.

Comment: the error was an error pointing to the location of the script on host system as not found when ran on target.That is: "/path/to/script/on/host not found".My doubt was answered by ruakh's solution.Thx

Answer (score 24):

The difference is that in this version:

```
<<EOF
...
EOF
```

the `...` functions roughly as a double-quoted string, performing parameter-expansions and command-substitutions and so on (specifically, in your case, replacing `$0` with the value of `$0`), whereas in this version:

```
<<'EOF'
...
EOF
```

the `...` functions roughly as a single-quoted string, and no such expansions are performed.

(See [§3.6.6 "Here Documents" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections).)

Answer (score 6):

The difference is whether the dollars and back quotes in the body of the here document are interpreted as the here document is expanded.

```
$ XYZ=pqr
$ cat <<EOF
> echo $XYZ
> EOF
echo pqr
$ cat <<'EOF'
> echo $XYZ
> EOF
echo $XYZ
$
```

You can try similar tricks with `$(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

`EOF` will expand `$` `$()`

`'EOF'` or `"EOF"` won't expand anything

Most careful thing is, all of `EOF` `'EOF'` `"EOF"` don't expand `*`

( Unless there is `*` in the result and  you unfortunately `echo` it )